# No sound through headphones while speakers work fine

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa, headphones

System details: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=ca96b1ad9d7f3d393a59566f0ca6b8ea765be023

I've tried everything I could find, asked on the IRC channel for help. I didn't get too far. After 5 hours of trying, I managed to get some low volume, distorted sound from my headphones. (My built-in speakers still work fine).

Any related details are included in the link pasted above.

The "sound" started coming form the headphones after I set every possible value in the alsamixer to the highest number and added the following code to the alsa-base.conf file :

```
options snd-pcsp index=-2
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=laptop
options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1 enable=yes
```

Comment: Sounds like you've got a broken headphone jack.

Comment: Hardware problem

Comment: I had the same problem, this fix worked! (see comment below, you need to shutdown your PC for the fix to take affect)

Thanks!

Comment: This does not work for me. I am using macbook, booting into MacOS and re-entering linux fix the issue for a while.

Answer (score 4):

FIXED IT: for anyone else having the same problem, I got it to work.
Edit the snippet of code I've posted in my original post into your alsa-base.conf file. (type gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf into a terminal)

Fully shut-down your computer and start it up again. Rebooting won't do it. Your headphones should now work.

Comment: What snippet of code? Ah nevermind, I didn't realise you posted the question to begin with. You should include it here too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reset user configuration (as described in the Troubleshooting section of https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio);
2. Make sure **Independent HP** is **Disabled** in `alsamixer`. To do that, just type `alsamixer` in a terminal, then choose your sound card (by pressing **F6**) and move to the **Independent HP** column.

Comment: I can't see an Independent HP column.

Answer (score -5):

This sounds characteristic of a broken headphones jack.  It's a broken piece of hardware.  Buy a USB sound card if you want headphones, or take it somewhere to be fixed (unless you're good with a soldering iron).

Comment: My headphones work fine when I'm booted into windows 10, so they are not the problem.