# No sound through headphones but works for internal speakers

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, thinkpad, headphones

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T440p. I'm not entirely sure what happened but my sound decided to go out for my headphones. The sound also went out for my speakers but in the process of fixing it, sound now works for speakers but not for my headphones. It's not just that pair, other headphones don't work.

Some output I saw others providing:

```
:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3232 Analog [ALC3232 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


~$ pacmd list-sinks
3 sink(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9950
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 371.33 ms
    max request: 64 KiB
    max rewind: 64 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 371.52 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0>
    module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.id = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "3"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf0630000 irq 32"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:03.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0c0c"
        device.product.name = "Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (ThinkPad T440p)"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "hdmi:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Intel Haswell HDMI"
        alsa.components = "HDA:80862807,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    active port: <hdmi-output-0>
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9959
    volume: front-left: 25350 /  39% / -24.75 dB,   front-right: 25350 /  39% / -24.75 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 366.40 ms
    max request: 64 KiB
    max rewind: 64 KiB
    monitor source: 1
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 371.52 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC3232 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC3232 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf0634000 irq 29"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "8c20"
        device.product.name = "8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (ThinkPad T440p)"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC3232"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0292,17aa220e,00100001"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
  * index: 2
    name: <ladspa_output.mbeq_1197.mbeq>
    driver: <module-ladspa-sink.c>
    flags: HW_MUTE_CTRL LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 25350 /  39%,   front-right: 25350 /  39%
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100%
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 365.79 ms
    max request: 128 KiB
    max rewind: 128 KiB
    monitor source: 3
    sample spec: float32le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 371.52 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    module: 18
    properties:
        device.master_device = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo"
        device.class = "filter"
        device.ladspa.module = "mbeq_1197"
        device.ladspa.label = "mbeq"
        device.ladspa.name = "Multiband EQ"
        device.ladspa.maker = "Steve Harris <steve@plugin.org.uk>"
        device.ladspa.copyright = "GPL"
        device.ladspa.unique_id = "1197"
        device.description = "LADSPA Plugin Multiband EQ on Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

Answer (score 4):

Fixed with [No sound through headphones while speakers work fine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686361/no-sound-through-headphones-while-speakers-work-fine?rq=1)

added

```
options snd-pcsp index=-2
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=laptop
options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1 enable=yes
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

and fully shutdown my laptop, removed the battery and booted it back up. Sound now works.

Comment: This actually does not work for me. Do we really have to remove the battery?

Comment: For me I am using macbook, after booting into the MacOS the headphone works for the next few boots.