# Poor sound through headphones while internal speaker works fine

Tags: drivers, sound, macbook-pro

I am using Macbook, in ubuntu my external headphone does not work while my internal speaker works. Does anyone know how to fix this? Do I have to install a perfect driver?

One fix I found is that I can boot into MacOS then after next few days, headphone works in Ubuntu then.

These two 8-year posts did not work for me.
[No sound through headphones but works for internal speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703637/no-sound-through-headphones-but-works-for-internal-speakers)
[No sound through headphones while speakers work fine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686361/no-sound-through-headphones-while-speakers-work-fine?rq=1)

```
╰$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CS4206 Analog [CS4206 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: CS4206 Digital [CS4206 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```